# PyQT project organization

Tags: python, pyqt4

I want to organize my PyQT project, I tried to put the UIs in a subfolder and import them like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('UI/gui_sensors')
from gui_sensors_extended import Ui_SensorsWindow_Extended
```

But it gives me error as it can't find ***Ui_SensorsWindow***, the ui-class that was inherited in ***Ui_SensorsWindow_Extended***

So, What do you suggest to organize my project? And how can I handle it in the code?

Comment: Put complete path in `sys.path` starting from root

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is one key thing to remember when structuring a python project: the directory of the currently running script is automatically added to the start of `sys.path`.

So if you put your `main.py` script *outside* of your package in a top-level container directory, this will guarantee that package imports will always work, no matter where the script is executed from. To illustrate, here is a simple project structure:

```
project /
    main.py
    package /
        __init__.py
        app.py
        ui /
            __init__.py
            mainwindow.py
```

The `main.py` script should be very minimal, and contain only something like  this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    from package import app
    sys.exit(app.run())
```

and within the `app` module, the gui modules would be imported like this:

```
from package.ui.mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
```

This same import syntax can be used anywhere within the package tree. So if you added another sub-package like this:

```
project /
    main.py
    package /
    ...
        dialogs /
            __init__.py
            search.py
```

then the `search` module would import its gui module like this:

```
from package.ui.search import Ui_SearchDialog
```

If you organize all your python projects in this way, there should never be any need to manipulate `sys.path` in order to get your local imports working correctly.

Comment: How would I go forth to call functionality residing in app.py from mainwindow.py then? Being that we want to separate code from UI

Comment: All of the program logic would be in *app.py*. The files in the *ui* directory would be generated by `pyuic`, and will only contain gui classes. These classes are simply imported into whatever module needs them. See [Using Qt Designer](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html#using-the-generated-code) in the PyQt Docs.

Comment: so people usually come up with their own designs and there is no autoloader?

Comment: I don't understand the line `sys.exit(app.run())` in `main.py`. Why is this necessary? Why does the `app` module have a `run` method? Where is this method defined?

Comment: @cbrnr. It is simply a function that starts the application - I suppose such a function is more commonly called `main()`.

Comment: I see. `QApplication`s are started with the `exec_` method, I think your answer would be even better if you explicitly wrote `sys.exit(app.exec_())` in `main.py`. But thanks in any case, you already helped me a lot!

Comment: @cbmr. I very deliberately made the `main.py` script as minimal as possible, so it certainly would not be appropriate to use `QApplication` there. Most applications do a lot more in the `main()` function than start a gui event-loop (e.g. parsing the command-line arguments). And the project structure in my answer can easily be adapted for use with *any* type of python application - not just ones that happen to use pyqt. The original question is only asking about how to get the imports working properly - so it's more to do with *project* structure than *application* structure.

Comment: The question was about a PyQt project specifically. At least mention that `app.run` is an arbitrary function that the user wants to run.

Comment: @cbrnr. I think you may have been mislead by the title of the question. When the OP uses the term "project organization", they are just talking about "directory structure". Specifically: how do I re-organize my folders so that the ui files are in a subfolder, and the imports still work correctly? They don't give any details about what their application is or how it works, because that is totally irrelevant. It is for that reason that I used `app.run()`, and made my answer as generic as possible.

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks for such a great project layout. Fumbling through object oriented in Python, I incorporated this in to my current structure. The one question that I have is if I place all the pyuic generated files into a subpackage ( ui or dialog) where do I add the py files with logic for each window ( same as main window, I guess). I generally inherit the py generated from pyuic into another py file and create action events on those.

Comment: @StatusQuo. They can go in the `package` directory, or in a sub-package within that. Once you have the core structure outlined in the first part of my answer, any module can import from any other module, so you are free to use whatever package structure you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the complete path using following method:

```
import sys
import os.path as osp
path = osp.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(osp.join(path, 'UI/gui_sensors'))
from gui_sensors_extended import Ui_SensorsWindow_Extended
```

`__file__` contains the path to current module